# How can I use PyPDF2 to update variable text to a form field?

Tags: python, pypdf

PyPDF2 update page form field values function working fine with hardcoded strings but nothing shows if using variable text.

I have tried using string variables like this

```py
writer.update_page_form_field_values(
    #writer.pages[0], {"Piece Weight": variableString} doesn't work
    writer.pages[0], {"Piece Weight": "hardcoded string"}#works 
)
```

as well as like this

```py
writer.update_page_form_field_values(
    #writer.pages[0], {"Piece Weight": f"{variableString}"} doesn't work
    writer.pages[0], {"Piece Weight": "hardcoded string"}#works 
)
```

I am expecting the final output file to show the text I store into a string variable within the field named "piece weight" but what actually happens is absolutely no data is displayed on in the field when a variable is applied to it.

UPDATE-

found that my issue was not that it refuses to show variable data, rather it was a matter of, my variable data not being updated after it is initialized.  I am creating it at one point

> variablestring = ""

and then later in the code i am attempting to change it within a function

```py
def onStart():
    variablestring = variableEntry.get()
```

This is an issue of scope as the variablestring within the function and outside the function are seen as separate memory spaces.

there in lies an issue however, I can not pass this function parameters as it needs to be automatically called by a

> tkinter.Button(form, text="start", command=onStart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final answer to my issue was to use the global tag to call the variable outside of the function into it.

```
variable = "te"
def onStart():
  global variable
  variable = variableEntry.get()
```

when reading about globals for python i misunderstood it as a declarative global and not a call global